# BackgroundDownloader The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm using C# and Windows Phone 8.1 as Universal.

I Have an issue with BackgroundDownloader. when I start a downloader, it gave me an exception:

```
Downloading http://localhost/MySong.mp3 to MySong.mp3 with Default priority, a95c00db-738d-4e22-a456-dc30d49b0a3b


A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Exception: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
```

here is my code:

```
        private void downladButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PumpUrl(txtUrl.Text);
        }
        async void PumpUrl(string url)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url) && CheckUrl(url))
                StartDownloadMethod(url);
            else
                await new MessageDialog("Looks like URL is invalid.\r\nPlease check your URL and try again"").ShowAsync();
        }
        public bool CheckUrl(string URL)
        {
            Uri source;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(URL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out source))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        public void StartDownloadMethod(string url, string fileName = null)
        {
            StartDownload(url, BackgroundTransferPriority.Default, false, fileName);
        }

        private async void StartDownload(string url, BackgroundTransferPriority priority, bool requestUnconstrainedDownload, string fileName = null)
        {
            Uri source;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(url.Trim(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out source))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Invalid URI.");
                return;
            }

            string destination = null;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
                try
                {
                    destination = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)).Trim();
                }
                catch { }
            else
                destination = Uri.UnescapeDataString(fileName).Trim();


            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destination))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("A local file name is required.");
                return;
            }

            StorageFile destinationFile = null;
            try
            {
                if (vars.localType == LocalType.SDCard)
                    destinationFile = await KnownFolders.RemovableDevices.CreateFileAsync(
    "Downloads\\Test App\\" + destination, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                else
                    destinationFile = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(
"Test App\\" + destination, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error while creating file: " + ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("Error while creating file: " + ex.Message); }

            if (destinationFile == null)
                return;


            BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(source, destinationFile);

            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Downloading {0} to {1} with {2} priority, {3}",
                source.AbsoluteUri, destinationFile.Name, priority, download.Guid));

            download.Priority = priority;
            Add(url, destination, download);
            if (!requestUnconstrainedDownload)
            {
                // Attach progress and completion handlers.
                await HandleDownloadAsync(download, true);
                return;
            }

            List<DownloadOperation> requestOperations = new List<DownloadOperation>();
            requestOperations.Add(download);

            UnconstrainedTransferRequestResult result;
            try
            {
                result = await BackgroundDownloader.RequestUnconstrainedDownloadsAsync(requestOperations);
            }
            catch (NotImplementedException)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    "BackgroundDownloader.RequestUnconstrainedDownloadsAsync is not supported in Windows Phone.");
                return;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Request for unconstrained downloads has been {0}",
                (result.IsUnconstrained ? "granted" : "denied")));

            await HandleDownloadAsync(download, true);
        }

        private async Task HandleDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation download, bool start)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Running: " + download.Guid);
                bool bb = false;
                foreach (DownloadOperation item in DownloadDB.activeDownloads)
                {
                    if (item != null && item.Guid == download.Guid)
                    {
                        bb = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!bb)
                    DownloadDB.activeDownloads.Add(download);

                Progress<DownloadOperation> progressCallback = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(DownloadProgress);
                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                AppendCancellationTokenSource(download, cts);

                if (start)
                    await download.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
                else
                    await download.AttachAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);

                ResponseInformation response = download.GetResponseInformation();

                DownloadDB.RemoveChildByGuid(download.Guid.ToString());
                DownloadDB.SaveDB();
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Completed: {0}, Status Code: {1}",
                    download.Guid, response.StatusCode));

            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException taskCanceled)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("TaskCanceledException: " + download.Guid + "\t" + taskCanceled.Message);
                DownloadDB.RemoveChildByGuid(download.Guid.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                DownloadDB.RemoveChildByGuid(download.Guid.ToString());
                DownloadDB.activeDownloads.Remove(download);
            }
        }
```

I used my code in other application 3 month ago and it works fine but in this application dosent work. Where I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The most likely cause is that it cannot find the file you specified.  Check the path to make sure that the file is actually there, and check the path that you're actually providing to the application to make sure they both match.

Comment: I checked, it's there. and path its match